# Manifest is not always detected

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

My manifest is working perfectly fine. I managed to install my app on both my desktop and mobile but for testing purposes I deleted the app and now Chrome can't detect the manifest. I managed to make him find it by restarting chrome but it only shows up for the first load of the page. After refreshing it's gone again. I also can't make the Install App banner to appear on my android device, too. I have enabled the `#enable-desktop-pwas` but it's not working again. How am I supposed to test it?